# How do I create a global key-binding in a gnome-shell extension

Tags: key-bindings, gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome, gnome shell version 3.24.2. I'm trying to create a gnome shell extension, and am using Javascript.

In my extension and in Javascript, how do I create a global key binding that is recognized from anywhere in Gnome? I want to bind a function to that key binding so that when the user presses the key combination then the said function is executed.

There's virtually no documentation on gnome-shell extension development. So asking here is my only option. Please don't refer me to the following stackoverflow question, since its answer is for Gnome 3.22 and I sincerely hope there's an easier way to create a key-binding: [Gnome Shell Extension Key Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325405/gnome-shell-extension-key-binding/42466781)

Answer (score 1):

There a pretty complete answer here: [How to handle keyboard events in gnome shell extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522031/how-to-handle-keyboard-events-in-gnome-shell-extensions/45272469#45272469)

You may find the easiest way is to use Gnome Shell's DBus interface, but dealing with shortcut conflicts and handling the signal callbacks is unavoidable:

> Bus Name: org.gnome.Shell -> Path: /org/gnome/Shell -> Interface:
>   org.gnome.Shell
>
> Relevant Methods:
>
> `GrabAccelerator(String accelerator, UInt32 flags) -> (UInt32 action)`
>   `UngrabAccelerator(UInt32 action) -> (Boolean success)`
>
> Signal:
>
> `AcceleratorActivate(UInt32, Dict of {String, Variant})`

Comment: thx for your reply. I'm now using the solution linked below, but I can only get it to work for "<ctrl><shift>a" and not for for instance "<ctrl><shift>" (note there's no last char such as "a". I get an error saying couldn't listen for this key binding.

Do you know how I can create partial key bidning such as "<ctrl><shift>" or "<ctrl>" using the solution I've linked below? 

https://superuser.com/questions/471606/gnome-shell-extension-key-binding/1182899#1182899

Comment: As far as I know, that's not possible, since those are both modifier keys and don't trigger an `accelerator-activated` event. You'll have to bind to `key-press-event` and decode the keyname from the keyval as described in the answer I linked to above (also to solution you linked to above is a repost of the solution you asked not to be linked to...)